# Mid-2014 15" rMBP: Crashes on OS 10.9.5

Tags: macbook-pro, video, crash, display, kernel

Update #2:

The MBP crashed at 1:31am in the morning while sleeping.

Console log and kernel panic log enclosed below:

========

Console Log:

```
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: RTC: PowerByCalendarDate setting ignored
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: Previous Sleep Cause: 5
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHI::prePCIWake - power up complete - took 0 us
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: The USB device Card Reader (Port 4 of Hub at 0x15000000) may have caused a wake by being disconnected
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 1 milliseconds
4/22/15 1:29:52.102 AM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.aslmanager) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8025ddec00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: TBT W (2): 0x0040 [x]
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8025ddec00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0x4000 ****
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: ARPT: 6123.466240: si_survive_perst_war: bar0win before 18003000, bar0win after 18001000
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
4/22/15 1:29:52.321 AM hidd[70]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
4/22/15 1:29:52.466 AM com.apple.time[162]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: ARPT: 6123.714665: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
4/22/15 1:29:52.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
4/22/15 1:29:52.484 AM UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Inactive
4/22/15 1:29:52.485 AM configd[18]: network changed: v4(en0-:192.168.0.175) DNS- Proxy-
4/22/15 1:29:53.000 AM kernel[0]: ARPT: 6124.706193: MacAuthEvent en0   Auth result for: 28:c6:8e:0a:ac:cf  MAC AUTH succeeded
4/22/15 1:29:53.000 AM kernel[0]: wlEvent: en0 en0 Link UP virtIf = 0
4/22/15 1:29:53.000 AM kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en0
4/22/15 1:29:53.000 AM kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 28:c6:8e:0a:ac:cf
4/22/15 1:29:53.000 AM kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 28:c6:8e:0a:ac:cf
4/22/15 1:29:53.000 AM kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en0
4/22/15 1:29:53.573 AM UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1655] en0: SSID 'Alpha Centauri' making interface primary (cache indicates network not captive)
4/22/15 1:29:53.573 AM configd[18]: network changed: DNS* Proxy
4/22/15 1:29:53.574 AM UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Evaluating
4/22/15 1:29:53.574 AM UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: en0: Not probing 'Alpha Centauri' (cache indicates not captive)
4/22/15 1:29:53.574 AM UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Authenticated
4/22/15 1:29:53.577 AM configd[18]: network changed: v4(en0!:192.168.0.175) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
4/22/15 1:29:53.669 AM hidd[70]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
4/22/15 1:29:53.000 AM kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
4/22/15 1:29:53.885 AM airportd[84]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “Alpha Centauri”. Bailing on auto-join.
4/22/15 1:29:55.000 AM kernel[0]: SMC::smcIH WARNING: unexpected interrupt: 0x55
4/22/15 1:29:55.000 AM kernel[0]: SMC::smcIH WARNING: unexpected interrupt: 0x54
4/22/15 1:29:56.079 AM apsd[82]: Unrecognized leaf certificate
4/22/15 1:29:56.542 AM spindump[762]: Saved diag report for powerstats version com.apple.SystemStats.Daily to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerstats_2015-04-22-012956_Davids-MacBook-Pro.diag
4/22/15 1:29:56.801 AM spindump[764]: Saved diag report for powerstats version com.apple.SystemStats.TopPowerEvent to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerstats_2015-04-22-012956-1_Davids-MacBook-Pro.diag
4/22/15 1:29:57.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
4/22/15 1:29:57.221 AM spindump[765]: Saved diag report for powerstats version com.apple.SystemStats.TopPowerEvent to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerstats_2015-04-22-012957_Davids-MacBook-Pro.diag
4/22/15 1:29:57.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
4/22/15 1:29:57.546 AM spindump[766]: Saved diag report for powerstats version com.apple.SystemStats.TopPowerEvent to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerstats_2015-04-22-012957-1_Davids-MacBook-Pro.diag
4/22/15 1:29:58.000 AM kernel[0]: ARPT: 6129.841476: MacAuthEvent en0   Auth result for: 28:c6:8e:0a:ac:cf  MAC AUTH succeeded
4/22/15 1:29:58.000 AM kernel[0]: wlEvent: en0 en0 Link UP virtIf = 0
4/22/15 1:29:58.000 AM kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en0
4/22/15 1:29:58.000 AM kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #0, bssid 28:c6:8e:0a:ac:cf
4/22/15 1:29:58.000 AM kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 28:c6:8e:0a:ac:cf
4/22/15 1:30:00.001 AM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.newsyslog) Throttling respawn: Will start in 3 seconds
4/22/15 1:30:02.000 AM kernel[0]: IOPPF: Sent cpu-plimit-notification last value 2 (rounded time weighted average 2)
4/22/15 1:30:02.695 AM Messages[552]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
4/22/15 1:30:03.531 AM AirPlayUIAgent[341]: 2015-04-22 01:30:03.531383 AM [AirPlayUIAgent] Changed PIN pairing: no
4/22/15 1:30:03.540 AM AirPlayUIAgent[341]: 2015-04-22 01:30:03.540389 AM [AirPlayUIAgent] Changed PIN pairing: no
4/22/15 1:30:09.333 AM WindowServer[91]: _CGXHWCaptureWindowList: No capable active display found.
4/22/15 1:30:37.936 AM ntpd[44]: ntpd: wake time set -0.604999 s
4/22/15 1:30:37.000 AM kernel[0]: ARPT: 6169.789852: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
4/22/15 1:30:37.000 AM kernel[0]: ARPT: 6169.789858: wl0: powerChange: *** BONJOUR/MDNS OFFLOADS ARE NOT RUNNING.
4/22/15 1:30:37.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
4/22/15 1:30:37.952 AM com.apple.time[162]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/22/15 1:30:37.955 AM com.apple.time[162]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: hibernate image path: /var/vm/sleepimage
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: efi pagecount 63
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 1) start 0xffffff81efb45000, 0xffffff81efbc5000
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 398 ms
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: pages 1443085, wire 478934, act 309149, inact 28740, cleaned 0 spec 279, zf 81264, throt 0, compr 0, xpmapped 0
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: could discard act 19073 inact 173815 purgeable 37908 spec 313923 cleaned 0
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall preflight pageCount 478934 est comp 50 setfile 1082130432 min 1073741824
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHI::prePCIWake - power up complete - took 0 us
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 0 milliseconds
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: VNOP_ALLOCATE(0) 8388608
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: [0xf44805000, 0x32000000]
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: [0xfa4805000, 0xe000000]
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: [0xfb2806000, 0x800000]
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: kern_open_file_for_direct_io(0) took 0 ms
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: Opened file /var/vm/sleepimage, size 1082130432, partition base 0x0, maxio 2000000 ssd 1
4/22/15 1:30:38.000 AM kernel[0]: hibernate image major 1, minor 0, blocksize 4096, pollers 5
4/22/15 1:30:58.000 AM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1429691458 0
```

=======

```
Kernel Panic:

    Anonymous UUID:       [Redacted]

    Wed Apr 22 01:31:02 2015
    panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff8004adcc1d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8004aaa7d8, type 14=page fault, registers:
    CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000008, CR3: 0x0000000007138000, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0
    RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff80050d0180, RCX: 0xffffff80050d0b30, RDX: 0xffffff80050d0b30
    RSP: 0xffffff81f1c23c70, RBP: 0xffffff81f1c23cd0, RSI: 0x0000000000000025, RDI: 0x000006a800010000
    R8:  0x00000000005ae000, R9:  0x00007fff7eb87000, R10: 0xffffff81f1c23ad0, R11: 0x0000000000001380
    R12: 0xffffff80050d0b30, R13: 0xffffff80287bdd40, R14: 0xffffff802572b1f8, R15: 0x0000000000000000
    RFL: 0x0000000000010203, RIP: 0xffffff8004aaa7d8, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
    Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000008, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x6

    Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
    0xffffff81f1c23900 : 0xffffff8004a23139 
    0xffffff81f1c23980 : 0xffffff8004adcc1d 
    0xffffff81f1c23b50 : 0xffffff8004af4486 
    0xffffff81f1c23b70 : 0xffffff8004aaa7d8 
    0xffffff81f1c23cd0 : 0xffffff8004aa851b 
    0xffffff81f1c23d00 : 0xffffff8004aa810e 
    0xffffff81f1c23d30 : 0xffffff8004a5676d 
    0xffffff81f1c23d80 : 0xffffff8004e828e8 
    0xffffff81f1c23ef0 : 0xffffff8004ee3b9f 
    0xffffff81f1c23f00 : 0xffffff8004e9cd4c 
    0xffffff81f1c23f20 : 0xffffff8004a4a57a 
    0xffffff81f1c23fb0 : 0xffffff8004ad7c67 

    BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

    Mac OS version:
    13F1077

    Kernel version:
    Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64
    Kernel UUID: 8B1A8FD1-2344-36C0-A7F5-D9D485A995FA
    Kernel slide:     0x0000000004800000
    Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004a00000
    System model name: MacBookPro11,2 (Mac-3CBD00234E554E41)

    System uptime in nanoseconds: 6171849840124
    last loaded kext at 1804735890114: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.2.1b5 (addr 0xffffff7f86a92000, size 20480)
    last unloaded kext at 1958699769711: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.2.1b5 (addr 0xffffff7f86a92000, size 16384)
    loaded kexts:
    com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
    com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
    com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.7f4
    com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.34
    com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.9d7
    com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
    com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   8.2.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.1.2
    com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   4.26.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
    com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  8.2.8
    com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.7f4
    com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.11
    com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
    com.apple.BootCache 35
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
    com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
    com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   842.21.65
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   683.4.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
    com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
    com.apple.security.quarantine   3
    com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  170.15
    com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.7f4
    com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   170.15
    com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
    com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
    com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
    com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
    com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.7f4
    com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
    com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
    com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
    com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
    com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
    com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    98.26
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.7f4
    com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
    com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
    com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.10
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    3.1.7
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    3.1.7
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.5
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.7
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    2.0.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 3.3.1
    com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
    com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
    com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
    com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.2
    com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
    com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
    com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
    com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
    com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
    com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
    com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
    com.apple.kec.pthread   1
    com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
    Model: MacBookPro11,2, BootROM MBP112.0138.B11, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.18f15
    Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
    Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
    Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
    AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (6.30.223.154.65)
    Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f4 15112, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
    Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
    USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
    USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
    USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
    USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
    Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```

========

I have a 3 week old mid-2014 15" retina MacBook Pro (integrated graphics only) that experiences constant freezes and crashes that first start when browsing the web (such as when watching a YouTube video) and soon propagates to all the other system apps. Eventually, given enough crashes, the system fails to boot.

Only a full format, followed by a PRAM reset, allows me to reinstall OS X and get back to work.

Additional info: MBP initially shipped with Yosemite. I formatted the SSD and installed Mavericks--too many bugs in Yosemite.

Also, problem seems to only occur when an external display is plugged-in (in my case a Dell U2713HM).

AHT shows all hardware to be 'normal.' DriveDx does not show anything alarming with the SSD (minus the fact that I'm wracking up forced shutdown errors from all the hard resets).

EtreCheck log attached. Can't seem to find any kernel panics in console, but maybe someone can help me dig deeper.

***Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate it!***

Comment: OK, nice info, could you also cop the console log at the times when it has problems.

Comment: Posted a large-ish console log above. Thank you so much, Buscar!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the Console log.

What I see is:

You use Firefox with some plugins that create problems.

Step one Disable Firefox add-ons and test without them. To do that click all the way to the right in Firefox menu bar, open the add-ons and disable them. If it works, enable plug ins one o´by one to check. Check your Firefox update to ver. 3702.

Also you need to repair your Fonts. Open the Font Book in the Applications and use Restore Standard Fonts.

Comment: Hi Buscar! I attempted to disable all plugins/extensions in Firefox yesterday and that didn't help The problem occurs even when Firefox is using youtube's HTML5 player. Also, the exact same issue occurs in Safari (which in my case has no extensions/plugins whatsoever). I have just updated Firefox to v37.0.2. Might the fonts issue be caused by having MS Office (and its associated font package)?

Comment: OK, that log does not show you using the youtube html5. As for the Fonts, you have lots of problems with them.

Comment: Stop using HTML5 and use Adobe Flash.

Comment: Hi Buscar, I've removed the fonts and re-enabled all of the plugins in firefox. So far so good. I will update you in a day or so and let you know if the issue crops up. However, it does surprise me that nothing terribly incriminating showed up in the console logs. No kernal panics or kext errors...

Comment: I know, it is disappointing not to see something like "5 seconds countdown to self destruct"...Panic ect.. but instead just having some Fonts misbehave :(